# How to set iptables rule to block ICMP packets between docker containers

Tags: docker, containers, ping, docker-network, icmp

I need to block containers from ping each other, so I want to block ICMP but only for docker.

I tried this rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j REJECT
```

But it did help so I tried also these two rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j DROP
```

I was still able to ping each container from **within** a container.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0 -p icmp -j DROP
```